# Finding the last value of the last column in an array of rows

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to interpret this code which is used to Sum all the values in the last column

```
rows.map(r => r[Object.keys(r)[Object.keys(r).length - 1]]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

What does it mean ? Can anyone suggest how can I rewrite this to give just the latest value in the last column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider if `rows` was:

```
rows = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, 
    {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}
];
```

The code is saying: for the 'last' column (which is `c`) sum the values in column `c`.

This bit:

`Object.keys(r).length - 1`

Establishes the number of properties in each row 'object' i.e. the 'last' column is the 'last' property and by using `-1` you know the index of the key. In the example each row has 3 columns and the index of `c` is 2.

This bit:

`Object.keys(r)[Object.keys(r).length - 1]`

Then returns the value `c` because it is at index 2 in the list of keys in each row object (assuming each row object has similarly named and ordered keys).

So the whole thing:

`rows.map(r => r[Object.keys(r)[Object.keys(r).length - 1]]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`

Is just saying the same as:

`rows.map(r => r["c"]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`

Except `c` has to be figured out - presumably you use this code and do not know the key for the 'last column'.

So to find the last value of the last column you don't need the `reduce` function you just want to know the number of rows in the array and deduct 1 to get the index e.g.:

`rows.map(r => r[Object.keys(r)[Object.keys(r).length - 1]])[rows.length - 1]`

```js
const rows = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}];

const finalColumnSum = rows.map(r => r[Object.keys(r)[Object.keys(r).length - 1]]).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

const finalValue = rows.map(r => r[Object.keys(r)[Object.keys(r).length - 1]])[rows.length - 1];

console.log(`Last column sum: ${finalColumnSum}`);

console.log(`Last column/ row value: ${finalValue}`);
```

Comment: great explanation !!!.....can you please tell how can i get the value from a particular column by using this same nomenclature

Comment: If you know the name of the column e.g. `b` then `rows.map(r => r["b"])[rows.length - 1]`

Comment: great..can i throw this value to a variable and use that variable to perform a function like so

`const finalValue = rows.map(r => r[Object.keys(r)[Object.keys(r).length - 1]])[rows.length - 1];

if (finalValue < 1000 ) {
  console.log(`Value is less that 1000: ${finalValue}`);
  }
  else if (finalValue >1000) {
    pronoun1 = 'they';
    pronoun2 = 'their';
    pronoun1_up = 'They';
 
  console.log(`Value is greater than 1000`);
  }
  else {
    throw 'Null';
  }`

Comment: Please go ahead and ask a new question about if..else statements. If this is the right answer you can use the green tick to mark it.

Comment: yes created new question,can you please post your answer there?
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306330/implementing-the-below-if-else-statement-is-this-right?noredirect=1#comment115454961_65306330